# download a set of files in Python error 403

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests-html

I get a message instead of an m3u file

{"user_info":{"auth":"0"}} how to download it note it is normally downloaded via telnet or on firefox

```html
import requests , json, re
url=https://pastebin.com/ysAGBfWU
r = s.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open(M3UPATH, 'wb').write(r.content)


<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
<script>(function(){var js = "window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'7b46e1ab58900ad6',m:'xJQTrtapPuDQCt.3_0Fn2hz050IeKVy.NcprhPCGQWk-1680918858-0-AZceAG7KQwJCbtSDys8C8WI49jukLE/V7uLbbPNrNfOV9UstmWW9wtwe31gblFjTf1FJJmnYgTErJoX1SigIg6ZOxI+MlNFqvkVq9N8oRjRLEx20eAQaWYxAaoULGH8XYoAcXigofcwqUu8aswJXEHUfvpcyhBuIhV0w6hLPwb/Y8xWitV+q5qno4FbYBclGx47/9nU7MnptDuvNADbwjmc=',s:[0x5036dfab36,0x567bc9c169],u:'/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b'};var now=Date.now()/1000,offset=14400,ts=''+(Math.floor(now)-Math.floor(now%offset)),_cpo=document.createElement('script');_cpo.nonce='',_cpo.src='/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/scripts/alpha/invisible.js?ts='+ts,document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_cpo);";var _0xh = document.createElement('iframe');_0xh.height = 1;_0xh.width = 1;_0xh.style.position = 'absolute';_0xh.style.top = 0;_0xh.style.left = 0;_0xh.style.border = 'none';_0xh.style.visibility = 'hidden';document.body.appendChild(_0xh);function handler() {var _0xi = _0xh.contentDocument || _0xh.contentWindow.document;if (_0xi) {var _0xj = _0xi.createElement('script');_0xj.nonce = '';_0xj.innerHTML = js;_0xi.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_0xj);}}if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {handler();} else if (window.addEventListener) {document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handler);} else {var prev = document.onreadystatechange || function () {};document.onreadystatechange = function (e) {prev(e);if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {document.onreadystatechange = prev;handler();}};}})();</script></body>
</html>
```